# How to routing in another component when use canActivate()

Tags: angular, routes, nativescript, canactivate

I want to navigate directly in here component `ResetPassIdComponent` whene I use canActivate(); Now, when I click for this component ResetPassIdComponent , my aplication navigate in first in `/outsidelogin/login` and in second in `resetPasswordRequest/:id`

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, private auth: LoginService) { }
    canActivate(): boolean {
        if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/outsidelogin/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

So in this canActivate() I have 2 conditions, first if I'm login and second if I'm not login navigate in `this.router.navigate(['/outsidelogin/login']);`

My routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'fp', component: FirstPageComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'outsidelogin',
    component: outsideloginComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginFirstComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    ]
  },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home/fp', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'resetPasswordRequest/:id', component: ResetPassIdComponent }
];
```

Please, Can you share with me any idea, how to solve my problem?

Comment: can you share (https://stackblitz.com) link with me because not properly get your point.

Comment: I demonstrate this demo https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=PmLIFr&v=2 I want to add a conditions in AuthGuard, if I have a id in `resetPasswordRequest/:id` I want to navigate direct in `ResetPassIdComponent`. In my demo it is assumed that Id is 123 and should navigate directly to the component ResetPassIdComponent

Comment: Can you see my demo please github.com/binaau/auth_guard After installed, please click this link stackoverflow.com/questions/53921510 and open with app. In this moment you can see that application in first navigate in login component and in second in reset pass. I want to navigate directly in reset pass only when I click link. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get parameter in resetPasswordRequest/:id, if login get the parameter as follow and convert string to number. You have to store your authentication token in browser cache.

```
    // import in resetPasswordeRquest Component.
    import { Route, AcivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'; 

    // inside component class;
    id: number;
    constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){
       this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
          this.id = +params.get('id');   
       }           
    }
```

Comment: I can get parameter in resetPasswordRequest. Only I want to create a condition in canActivate if I have a ID my app navigate in resetPasswordRequest, else navigate in `this.router.navigate(['/outsidelogin/login']); Also, I have a aplication mobile in Nativescript
`

Comment: why not use authguard in router? like "{ path: 'resetPasswordRequest/:id', component: ResetPassIdComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]};

Comment: I use that but nothing happens, is a similar problem. Because, in AuthGuard I don't have a condition that controller for this id

Comment: correct me if i m wrong, 1. you have first page with login component & register component. 2. after login success, go to resetpasswordRequest component 3. after login fail, go to register component. One more thing is you should check not authunticated and return false rather than return true first.

Comment: 1. I have first page with login component & register component. . 2. After login succes go to (FirstPageComponent), else go to  LoginFirstComponent . 3. In login Component I have a link that reset a password, when click button I send a link in my email, when I click a link from email, I want to go in ResetPassIdComponent. The problem is in this part. I click a link from email, open aplication and application in first go to LoginFirstComponent  and in second in ResetPassIdComponent. I want to go directly in ResetPassIdComponent

Comment: When my application is open my application go to FirstPageComponent, because this is a condition in AuthGuard.

Comment: I try something like in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921510/how-to-execute-in-first-a-function-and-in-second-canactivate

Comment: so the first condition in app is logged in?

Comment: Can you see my demo please github.com/binaau/auth_guard After installed, please click this link stackoverflow.com/questions/53921510 and open with app. In this moment you can see that application in first navigate in login component and in second in reset pass. I want to navigate directly in reset pass only when I click link. Thank you!